# Find closed form of $f(x)=x^2 \cdot \lfloor {\frac{1}{x^2}}\rfloor$

Tags: functions

Yesterday I asked a question about the continuity of $f(x)=x^2 \cdot \lfloor {\frac{1}{x^2}}\rfloor$ and we found out that $f(x)=0$, $\forall x>1$. Now I want to find its closed form over the reals. Now, since $f$ is even, suffice it to find its closed form on $(0,1)$ and we are done. How to do this?

Comment: Why do you not consider the form $x^2\cdot\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x^2}\right\rfloor$ "closed"?

Comment: My teacher claimed that this function can be expressed through a more "beautiful" relation. I agree that the term "closed" is not the most appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "closed form" is a little soft, but I'll go with the Wikipedia entry which states

> In mathematics, a closed-form expression is a mathematical expression
>   that can be evaluated in a finite number of operations.

Using this definition, $x^2\cdot\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x^2}\right\rfloor$ **is** a closed form.

---

However, for analyzing $f$, perhaps a better way to represent the function is to look at its values on the interval $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right]$. If $x$ is on this interval, then $f(x)$ will equal $n\cdot x^2$ which tells you both that the function *is* continous on each such interval, but is not continuous on the edges.

Comment: Thank you! How did you come up with that interval?

Comment: @MathEnthusiast I considered the question "when is the function $\left\lfloor\frac1{x^2}\right\rfloor$ constant?"

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\frac1{x^2}=n+t$$ where $n$ is a natural and $t$ a fractional part (in $[0,1)$).

Then

$$\begin{cases}x_n(t)=\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+t}},
\\f_n(t)=\dfrac n{n+t}\end{cases}$$ are parametric equations of the curve pieces, in terms of the parameter $t$, indexed by $n$.

The endpoints of the curves are $\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}},1\right)$ and $\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}},\dfrac n{n+1}\right)$. They are aligned on the horizontal $y=1$ and the parabola $y=1-x^2$.

All these expressions are closed-forms *stricto sensu*.